# Is it okay to store bamboo flooring in the garage before installation?

Tags: flooring

I just purchased some Cali Bamboo strand bamboo from a local installer that arrived yesterday. The installer was here to receive it (I was at work) and stacked it in the garage, boxes unopened.

The [manufacturer's website](http://www.calibamboo.com/how_to_acclimate_hardwood_flooring.html) recommends opening the boxes and sticker-stacking bamboo in the house , but the installer said the garage is fine. I wasn't able to get a hold of the manufacturer over the weekend to confirm that the garage was definitely a bad idea, but my understanding and some internet searching seemed to suggest otherwise.

Can anyone weight in on how big of a deal it is to have it in the garage rather than inside the house? It's about 1800 sq/ft worth, so I don't want to move it myself or make a big stink with the installer before I confirm that garage is definitely a no-go.

I'm in SF Bay Area (East Bay) and the bamboo came from Los Angeles warehouse -- pretty similar climate. I'm not sure what the temp / humidity difference between the house and the garage is, but overnight outside temp is about 20-25 degrees from daily high / interior temp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you live in a climate where you basically have your windows open most of the time and there is no heat or air conditioning then your flooring needs to be in your house 2-4 weeks (differs by wood type and climate).

So given your conditioned space in San Fran I would say that you need to move it in.  The wood needs to be in a close approximation to the installed environment.

I don't know your installer but I would be highly highly skeptical of his knowledge and abilities given the advise.  This is flooring 101.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up finding info on the manufacturer website that says garage is not an appropriate location.